# Creating a Custom Slider

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have created a custom slider, but the ValueChanged event is not triggered when changing the value of the slide, anyone can point out the reason why.

```
using Mobile.Resources;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Mobile.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SliderControl : Grid
    {
        #region Bindable Property

        public event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> SliderValueChanged;
        public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs> ValueChanged;

        public static readonly BindableProperty MinimumValueProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("MinimumValue", typeof(double), typeof(SliderControl), defaultValue: 0.00);

        public static readonly BindableProperty MiddleValueProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("MiddleValue", typeof(double), typeof(SliderControl), defaultValue: 50.00);

        public static readonly BindableProperty MaximumValueProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("MaximumValue", typeof(double), typeof(SliderControl), defaultValue: 100.00);

        public static readonly BindableProperty SliderValueProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SliderValue), typeof(double), typeof(SliderControl), defaultValue: 0.00);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ValidationExceedMessageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ValidationExceedMessage", typeof(string), typeof(SliderControl), defaultValue: "Limits exceeded");

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidationExceedProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("IsValidationExceed", typeof(bool), typeof(SliderControl), defaultValue: false);

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public double MinimumValue
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinimumValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public double MiddleValue
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MiddleValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MiddleValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public double MaximumValue
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaximumValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public double SliderValue
        {
            set => SetValue(SliderValueProperty, value);
            get => (double)GetValue(SliderValueProperty);
        }

        public bool IsValidationExceed
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsValidationExceedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsValidationExceedProperty, value); }
        }

        public string ValidationExceedMessage
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValidationExceedMessageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValidationExceedMessageProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public SliderControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Method

    private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            try
            {
                int.Parse(e.NewTextValue);
                this.SliderValue = double.Parse(e.NewTextValue);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                this.SliderValue = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.SliderValue = 0;
        }

        ValidateNumericValue();
        SliderValueChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    private void OnSliderValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        SliderValue = args.NewValue;

        ValidateNumericValue();
        ValueChanged?.Invoke(sender, args);
    }
```

This is the XAML.cs of SliderControl.cs, I'm also missing the event where if I change the slider value it should be reflected in the Entry component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Grid
    x:Class="Mobile.Controls.SliderControl"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Mobile.Common"
    xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Mobile.Controls"
    x:Name="component"
    RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
    VerticalOptions="Center">

<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Slider Maximum="{x:Binding MaximumValue, Source={x:Reference component}}"
                Minimum="0"
                WidthRequest="300"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Value="{x:Binding SliderValue, Source={x:Reference component}}"
                ValueChanged="OnSliderValueChanged"/>
        <Entry x:Name="SliderText"
               Placeholder="0"
               WidthRequest="50"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <Label Text="0"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               MinimumWidthRequest="100"/>
        <Label Text="{x:Binding MiddleValue, Source={x:Reference component}}"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="120,0,0,0"
               MinimumWidthRequest="100"/>
        <Label Text="{x:Binding MaximumValue, Source={x:Reference component}}"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               Margin="120,0,0,0"
               MinimumWidthRequest="100"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

This is a new instance for creating a dynamic slider control.

```
private void GenerateSliderContent(SQViewModel question)
{
    if (question.Entity.QuestionAnswer != null)
    {
        var slider = new SliderControl();

        var maxValue = question.Entity.MaxPrice ?? 100;
        var minValue = question.Entity.MinPrice ?? 0;

        slider.MaximumValue = Math.Max(minValue, maxValue);
        slider.MinimumValue = Math.Min(minValue, maxValue);
        slider.MiddleValue = slider.MaximumValue / 2;
        slider.WidthRequest = 100;
        slider.IsEnabled = !this.IsReadOnly;

        slider.SliderValue = question.Answer == null ? 0 : question.Answer.Entity.ValueNumeric.Value;

        slider.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => Slider_ValueChanged(question, e.NewValue);

        this.Children.Add(slider);
    }
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(SQViewModel question, double value)
{
    if (question.Answer != null)
    {
        question.Answer.Entity.ValueNumeric = value;
    }
    else
    {
        SAnswer answer = new SAnswer
        {
            SurveyId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            AccountId = AccountId,
            STId = question.Entity.STId,
            STQAnswerId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            STQId = question.Entity.Id,
            ValueNumeric = value,
        };

        question.Answer = new SAnswerViewModel(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to have a handler for the Slider control that in turn raises your custom SliderControl changed event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to the code below.

1. Add the `ValueChanged` in your SliderControl Xaml:

   ```
   <Slider Maximum="100"
                Minimum="0"
                WidthRequest="300"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"                    
                ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"
                Value="{x:Binding SliderValue, Source={x:Reference component}}"/>
   ```
2. Register the event in SliderControl code behind:

   ```
    public event EventHandler<ValueChangedEventArgs> ValueChanged;
    private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
   ```
3. Usage: I provide a simple code about how to do this in Xaml, you could do this in c# code as well.

   ```
   <local:SliderControl ValueChanged="SliderControl_ValueChanged"></local:SliderControl>
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Wendy Zang, I updated my post together with your implementation. However, when I tried to add the SliderValue to Text property of my Entry the Slider becomes unresponsive. This is because I want a behavior where when I adjust the slider the value should reflect in the entry, what is currently working right now is when I enter a value in the Entry it reflects in the Slider, I want the vice versa behavior.

Comment: If you want to make the slider the value reflect in the entry, you could do something like `entryName.Text =   e.NewValue.ToString() ;` in `Slider_ValueChanged` event of `SliderControl `. Due to i do not have the whole code to check, maybe some conflicts exists.

Comment: Yeah I also tried that one, but the slider becomes unresponsive also. I dunno is it because it also fires the TextChanged event and it produce delays or what. The code from the top is already been updated with latest code.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize color, thumb image, and track color easily. Basic customization can be done in two ways:

- From the Attributes Inspector
- Programmatically in the viewDidLoad()

this is [link](https://github.com/darshanPatel16/Custom-UISlider-Demo)

Comment: Hi @Binal Nasit,

Sorry I'm just new about this customization and not fully understand the swift coding. So with the current implementation that I have, should I also declare a ValueChanged event in my SliderControl.cs?

Comment: he is asking a question about a custom Xamarin Forms control, how does a link to an iOS Swift demo project help?